# Access bean defined in Annotation Spring config from Groovy Spring config

Tags: java, spring, groovy

I am using GenericGroovyApplicationContext to load my groovy and xml spring configurations. But I also have a few legacy @Configuration classes that need to be loaded. Problem is Groovy configuration is not able to reference any beans defined in @Configuration classes. This is all I am doing.

```
GenericGroovyApplicationContext ctx = new GenericGroovyApplicationContext();
ctx.load("classpath:spring/SpringConfig.groovy");
AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader configReader = new AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader(ctx);
configReader.register(JavaConfig.class);
ctx.refresh()
```

I also tried using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, but same problem, beans defined in groovy config cannot reference beans defined in @Configuration classes.

I know it is documented that Groovy and xml work nicely together, but not sure if this is even supported. Are there any work arounds?

Comment: Does the logging say anything useful if you set the level to DEBUG? Do the java annotated beans end up in ctx if you remove the references between groovy and java beans?